# Weird deployment issue

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

We're using CruiseControl.Net to do our continuous integration of our web applications.

we build the project, zip it up, copy it to the integration server. A littel bit later,
the wbe.config is cached away, the folder delted, the zip file unzipped recreating the folders, etc, then the web.config is copied back.

the issue is that somwhere in the process, one of the folders (not always the same one)
will have it's permissions totally hosed.

even the owner can't open teh folder to look at the contents.

We reboot, and everything is golden, we can delete the folder and redeploy and everythign works.

My question is, other than if anyone has expereinced anything like this, is 
what tools do you suggest to try to figure out what exactly has the permissions messed up
that is nolonger doign so after rebooting.

I figure if I can get a clue about what, I can figure out why.

Thanks,

E-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't remember the details But it was an obscure security setting on the Network our IT guys tweaked and it works now. I'm sorry I can't remember any more info, but I figured even this will be of some help incase someone else runs into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try finding a way to run cruisecontrol.net as a limited user, that way it can't set permissions as something higher.